# Минификация JS, CSS и картинок

Tags: оптимизация, веб-программирование, минификация

Мне нужно минифицировать JS, CSS и картинки. Сервер на Apache.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста как сделать максимально автоматизированно, а не сжимать по файлу и раскидывать по папкам.

Можно ли возложить минификацию на сервер установив PageSpeed Module и настроив .htaccess (или другой модуль) или это создаст слишком большую нагрузку?

Если вручную, то какие есть инструменты для пакетной обработки?

В общем у кого есть опыт поделитесь пожалуйста...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Процесс минификации можно проводить не постоянно при каждом новом запросе(динамически), а статически, т.е сразу перед выкладыванием в продакшн.

Для этого существует множество автоматизированных решений.
Одно из таких - **[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)**.

Грант использует систему "заданий" и плагинов, что делает его в этом плане достаточно гибким.

Answer (score 0):

У таких решений, как оптимизация сайта не может быть чудесных таблеток - одного простого решения. Над оптимизацией отдельных сайтов колдуют целые отделы, в этом и вся сложность.

Вкратце, что можно сделать - это прописать в htaccess управление разными модулями апача для максимальной оптимизации сайта. Вот наткнулся недавно  на хороший пример кеширования: [Правильное кэширование средствами htaccess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554511/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-htaccess)

Там уже кешируются текстовые форматы и включен Gzip

Если хотите что-то еще, нужно дополнительно минифицировать (обфусцировать) js/css файлы. Но это чаще делается от того, чтобы Ваш фронт-енд не скопировали и в легкую не начали пользовать на другом проекте.

Также необходимо объединять все файлы ксс воедино, а лучше инлайново встраивать (копировать из style.css) в хедер, в тег  - выглядит по-дурацки и устаревшим, но гуглу нравится. То же самое можно проделать с js и подключать его перед закрывающим . Но это все общие рекомендации и в частных случаях могут делать только хуже.

Также для больших сайтов с куче фотографий и бесконечной прокруткой необходимо использовать lazyload для картинок. Сами картинки также должны быть предварительно оптимизированы. Недостаток непопадания картинок в индекс лечится добавлением в отдельный sitemap именно для картинок.

Все это делается с помощью плагинов на том же вордпресс. Но плагины кеширования создают дополнительные запросы на сервер и в бд в процессе работы, поэтому в плане оптимизации это тоже палка о двух концах.

Будущее действительно за автоматизированными и общепринятыми решениями типа grunt.