# Правильное кэширование средствами htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Сейчас в htaccess написано что-то вроде
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
У этого решения есть явный недостаток - если вдруг я захочу обновить файл стилей, до пользователей моё обновление дойдёт через неделю. Как обойти это не меняя срок в expires?
// я читал про Last-modified,  однако не смог понять что к чему. Прошу дать как можно более развернутый ответ(или с ссылками на источники, язык любой)
Речь идёт только о кешировании на стороне клиента.

Comment: "Средствами .htaccess" вообще ничего не кэшируется. Никогда, нипочему и низачем.  `Кэширование осуществляется на другом уровне. `с ссылками на источники`  Пожалуйста: запрос в любой поисковик "как кэширует веб-сервер", "кэширующий proxy", и т.д.

Comment: @gottar, вы не так меня поняли, наверное, и оказались излишне агрессивны. Перечитайте статью - никто не говорит о кэшировании на сервернои уровне. Речь идёт об управлении кэшем на стороне клиента

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пример настроек кэширования [источник (Попытка номер раз создать почти идеальный htaccess — Habr)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/154643/):

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
AddHandler cgi-script .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/xml .xml
AddType application/octet-stream .doc .mov .avi .pdf .xls 
# ForceType application/x-httpd-php

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
    <FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
    #отключить кэширование
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    #по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    #кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"
    #кэшировать xml файлы на десять минут
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

Для того что бы сбросить стили в html необходимо будет просто прописать версию файла (get параметр) и тогда у пользователей закешируются новая версия, но Вы же не выпускаете новый стиль каждый час.

Comment: огромное спасибо, ровно то, что надо

Comment: `Для того что бы сбросить стили в html необходимо будет просто
 прописать версию файла (get параметр)` Можно подробнее? Версию css файла? И как (где/куда) прописать параметр get?

Comment: Например: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css?ver=2.0">